# Download an file that have been submitted with post method

Tags: php, html, server, client

how to download a file that have been submitted in a php post method?
Here is my shot with an image, i have tried a lot of stuff on the server side but it ain't working.

The client is this:

```
<form action="Server.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h1>5</h1>
<p>Upload an image</p>
<input type = "file" name = "d5" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

I want the server to download the file uploaded by a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list it with html Tag `<a>` with the location of the file in `href` atribute. Need to create the folder `uploads`.
If you have any other error, leave a comment.
Look the sample:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="server.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      Select image to upload:
      <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

server.php

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
  echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
  echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
  echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="index.php">retornar ao index</a><br>

    <a href="
        <?php echo $target_file; ?>" download >link for download </a>

    <br>
    

</body>
</html>
```